# About the ProtocolBuffers on Android Platform

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I just want to use ProtocolBuffers on Android Platform,but seems the Android jar package was so large that make my apk more and more large then using it before. Does any one has some resolution for it?

Comment: How big is "too big"? How small would be "small enough"? Any package will take some space... have you tried using the `option optimize_for = CODE_SIZE;` or `option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME` options?

Comment: where are you getting your jar from because I'm using the source not a jar file and mine isn't large at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem,  that most of java libraries are not suitable  for android due to 
big size (as there is no size constaint in server app developemtn,  pure java libraries tend top be bloathed).  You may try to use proguard to cull classes not used in your project, or lobby developers to provide android-friendly packaging with smaller granularity jars

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Third party addons](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) there are several Java ME implementations which may work for you.  In particular [protobuf-j2me](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-j2me/) claims to be

- 22 kb jar
- Android 1.5 compatible

There are some limitations but it could be just what you are looking for